# Mobile phone in room missing calls

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, mobile-phone

I always keep my phone in my room and go to watch TV so I end up missing calls. I don't want to keep the phone with me all times and still get some sort of notification about a call or message I am getting while being anywhere else in the house. Is there any device that my phone can pair with using Bluetooth or WiFi such that that phone is in my room while the device is in the TV room and will ring if I get a call and I can probably attend the call on that device itself with optional features like number display, making calls, contacts, messages, 3.5 mm port, etc?

Comment: There are [bluetooth cordless phones](http://www.vtechphones.com/telephones/cordless-phones/connect-to-cell).

Comment: which operator are you on ??

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you looking for a device that is smaller or wearable or something? Because it sounds kind of like you just want an extra phone to mirror your primary device.

Answer (score 2):

Most wearables have this functionality. The Charge 3 performs this function well. It will vibrate when the phone rings and show you who is calling and when you get a text. It has good range over Bluetooth. If you are willing to spend more, you can get more features from a Samsung or Apple smart watch.

Answer (score 0):

Pair the phone with a laptop or desktop PC. Both [Windows 10](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-connect-windows-10-and-android-using-microsofts-your-phone-app) and [Linux](https://vitux.com/how-to-see-android-notifications-on-the-ubuntu-desktop/) support that functionality.

On screen popup notifications are standard, and you can add audibles for that purpose. I can answer calls if I pick up in time.